# How can I treat a string like a list?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, list

Let's say this is my list:

```
current_fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']
```

My goal is to loop through each fruit in the list and add the name of the fruit onto a certain formatted string somehow. For example, this could be the string format for that list: `"Fruits: apple, orange, lemon"` so it would have commas and spaces after each item.

I know I could do this manually by adding each index/place in the list onto the string, but I want it to be dynamic since the fruits in current_fruits change around.

Comment: What *have* you tried? You do know that the naive solution using a `for` loop (like `for fruit in current_fruits: ...`) is "dynamic"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
I have tried manually adding each index place on the string, as I said in the question details, but the index range changes each time so it would have to be dynamic. I am aware about the `for` loop but I was not sure how to use it in the case of formatting strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.format` to format the string as required. And you can use `str.join` to join element in a list.

**Ex:**

```
current_fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon']
print("Fruits: {0}".format(", ".join(current_fruits)))
```

**Output:**

```
Fruits: apple, orange, lemon
```